# Attribute error - object attribute "activated" is read-only

Tags: python, animation, game-engine

I am very new at coding and I am doing a school project in Blender. I have a character created and some animations (walk, stand) done. I have a program that moves the character and now I want to make the animations play while I control it.

I have four if statements (if pressing W go forward and all that) and that works. I am trying now to make the “standing” animation play while NONE of the keys are pressed, so I put it in the “else” statement. The armature has an Action actuator in the logic bricks, an I called it with python like this:

```
else:
    actani.action = “ARMATUREAction.002”
    actani.frameStart = 1.0
    actani.frameEnd = 70
    actani.blendIn = 5
    actani.mode = 4
    actani.priority = 1
    co.activate = (“animacion”)
```

But when I run it it doesn’t work and it tells me this error:

```
Attribute error: “SCA_PythonController” object attribute “activate” is read-only
```

I have been looking for a solution but I found nothing. Could somebody help please?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! I don't know much about the BGE, unfortunately, but hopefully someone else can help you. I edited your question to improve the formatting -- Markdown can be a little tricky. (: If you don't agree with any change I made, please let me know!

Comment: `activate` is a function that you call, not a property that you assign a value to. Have a look at the example [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/84858/935).

Comment: @SilverWolf Everythi g is fine, thank you so much!!!!! This community is so kind!!!

Comment: @sambler Thank you very much!! I'll try to make It work and I'll post if I make It :)